# Java Netbeans does not have enough memory to compile

Tags: java, netbeans

Currently Im doing my FYP for my bachelors degree.

I'm using Netbeans 7.2.

Just now I got a message saying that "not enough memory to compile" when I run the project, it loads the main GUI of my application, but when I clicked the menu items, following error appears.

> Exception in thread `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PreProcessing/Segmentation`
>
> Preprocessing and Segmentation are classes in my project

Can I fix this by reinstalling Netbeans and open this project again?

Comment: You should have started your study earlier ;) Check the build path and increase the heap space

Comment: Post your code. Also, NoClassDefFoundError usually means you don't have `public static void main` defined or have the file name wrong.

Comment: @goldenparrot he had already started his application, looking for `main` is therefore futile.

Comment: I don't see anything about memory in the exception you gave us, could you please provide the full stack trace?

Comment: @goldenparrot :no this happened just after the not enough memory message, until then the program ran perfectly.

Comment: @owlstead: site doesn't allow me to add the whole stack trace. I think the memory problem is ok now(although i didnt do anything to fix).this error occured just after that. i didnt change anything. i just did run it just after the message.

Comment: I think something is wrong with your classpath. I think it is trying to look for a class named "PreProcessing/Segmentation" which it then cannot find as it is not a correct class name. Normally the exceptions are for one class at a time.

Comment: @owlstead : how can i fix it?

Comment: Not a clue unfortunately, this will be mostly debugging the class path and class loaders. That's tricky without access to the source and development environment. We can only comment on the things you post here, so try to show as much as possible (we'll close it as too localized later :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, press shift-f11 to do a clean build. Pay attention to the output window to make sure that everything compiles OK.

If it does, then right click on your project in the projects window (on the left by default), and select properties. Next select Run on the left. Then in the dialog on the right in the VM Options field, enter something like `-XMx 512M`. This will tell the JVM running your process to limit its memory usage to 512 megabytes. Pick a higher or lower number as you see fit. Do not pick a larger number than you have RAM on your machine.

Then try running your project.

Comment: but still give this error.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: PreProcessing/Segmentation

i think i have to add these two cllasses to the classpath manually.
how can i do it @Bill

Comment: I have more classes but only these two classes are missing from the class path. is it possible that the ide itself remove them from the classpath when there was a memory shortage. how can i add them back.

Comment: No classes cannot remove themselves from the classpath on memory shortage; you *must* get a memory error somewhere in the hierarchy, and normally those are not caught, except when `Throwable` is caught or if they happen in separate threads.

Comment: Please add the stack trace to your question. I don't think what you think is happening is happening.

Answer (score -1):

I still dont know the reason this happend but i fix this issue.
what i did was coppy the project folder to another location and open it from netbeans again and it works fine now.

Comment: you can do one thing that just clean your directory and close Netbeans and Restart it and that way that may get solved. i did it and its solved.